# I am no longer able to vote or comment, and am only able to answer a question. What changed?

Tags: bug, firefox, browsers

I see that changes have been recently made.

[New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page)

The timing coincides with my inability to comment in most parts of the SE network, or even vote up or down on anything.  Any click on a link to comment, or a button to vote, takes me immediately to the top of the page in the browser.  I am unable even to click on a link to show more comments, for those pages where the comments were extended.

I have purged all cookies in my browser, and restarted it, opening only an SE page afterward, to no avail.

(I cannot even click on the "Review your question" button...but fortunately, pressing "Enter" in the Tags input field triggers the submit function--which is how I post this.)

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using because it needs to be >=74 If you're using an old version then the duplicate answers certainly **do apply** in your case.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share your console errors. Basically, you only need to press `Ctrl + Shift + J`, but there are more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console#opening_the_browser_console).

Comment: It would be super useful, in *any* questions of this nature to include the browser *and* version.

Comment: @bad_coder OP recently said in another post that they are using [Firefox 48.0.2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370447/237989) -- so most likely the same bug as in the duplicate. No need to reopen this

Comment: If you are using FF earlier than [version 78](https://caniuse.com/usage-table) you fall into the 0.00% category - almost nobody uses a version that out of date. Following the 1st duplicate link a couple of links deep takes you to our [officially supported](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/) browser list, additional versions work but only those are officially supported.